# How to override a java method from groovy

Tags: java, groovy

I have a groovy class that has the ability to write its output to a `StringWriter` - (via a `setStringWriter` method).

In java I would use the following code:

```
filter.setStringWriter(new StringWriter(){
   @Override
   public void write(String string){
       // do something with the string
   }
});
```

For Groovy I'm told to use a closure, I've tried the following with no luck:

```
def s =  {String line -> print line} as StringWriter
filter.setStringWriter(s)
```

or

```
filter.setStringWriter{String line -> print line}
```

How do I go about doing this, or is it even possible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The following [link](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+way+to+implement+interfaces) gives a clue, although it only mentions interfaces.

The following works with Groovy 1.6.1:

```
def s =  [ write: { String line -> print line} ] as StringWriter
filter.setStringWriter(s)
```